# Rails passing form_for object to partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, partials, actionview

I would like to pass the `form_for` object to a partial:

```
<%= form_for @price do |f| %>
   ...
   <%= render :partial => "price_page", :object => @price, :as => :f %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

When I call:

```
f.radio_button
```

Brings the error:

```
undefined method `radio_button' for #<Price:0x3cb1ed0>
```

How can I use `f` as I usually would in this partial?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try passing form object as local
 `<%= render :partial => "price_page", :locals=>{:f=>f} %>`

Comment: Only problem I had with this is you can't include `nested_form` inside the partial.  Returns error.

Answer (score 10):

You can pass form builder object as a local variable like below,

```
<%= form_for @price do |f| %>
     <%= render :partial => "price_page", :locals => { :f => f } %>
<% end %>
```

in your partial file you will be receiving form builder as a local variable "f", you can use like below,

```
  <% f.radio_button, {} %>
```

Comment: Yea but only a few minutes after!

Comment: Yes, SO i brutal about rushing to be the first to answer.

Answer (score 6):

I ran across this question trying to figure out how to get a form builder into a partial without an additional form tag.  That's the primary use case I could think of for this question, so I'm adding this answer for future visitors.

To solve my problem, I have my form_for in my layout and I render my partial passing only the model.  In my partial I use [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for%20fields_for).

Looks (something) like this:

```
= form_for @price do |f|
   ...
   = render partial: "price_page", object: @price, as: 'price %>
   ...
```

Then, my partial has this:

```
= fields_for price do |f|
   ...
```